# How to remove the header in Android WebView? (While Loading)

Tags: javascript, android, android-layout, android-webview

I want to remove the header of the website in android '`WebView`'. With the Code that I have, it works. But the problem is that the '`WebView`' is removing the header after the page loaded completely. I want to remove it, while it is loading.

Thats the code snippet:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];"
                        + "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
                        "})()");

                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];"
                        + "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
                        "})()");
            }
        });
```

Comment: yes it is working fine. All you need to do is  mask the entire screen until the entire site loads and remove it.

Comment: I'am very new on Android Studio. How can I create a mask, while it is Loading? Is it a new Layout Screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest way is to inject Javascript in `onLoadResource()` method. Put it inside try-catch block since `WebView` will not know about the element before it has been loaded:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
           ...

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {

                try {
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:(window.onload = function() { " +
                            "(elem1 = document.getElementById('id1')); elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem1); " +
                            "(elem2 = document.getElementById('id2')); elem2.parentNode.removeChild(elem2); " +
                            "})()");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
}
```

Comment: @Sinan Glad I could help :)

Comment: Currently, `WebChromeClient` doesn't have `onLoadResource `.
Use `WebViewClient` instead

Answer (score 6):

ANDROID WebView-Remove header or any tag from Webpage in Android

Let's understand how's it possible, in my case I had loaded url in webview and look like below screenshot,

[image]

> Now from the above view if we want to remove the header and menu
>   portion of the Webpage. We need to use **JSOUP** lib with the help of
>   which you can remove the unnecessary portion of webpage.

**STEPS**

1. Add jsoup lib in your app level build gradle

   > compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
2. Now In activity we will use Async task as we parse / remove some html tags that leads to network operations which cannot be done directly on UI Thread. Async Task allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread. It has three methods commonly used.

   > onPreExecute():-Is used to display progress bar
   >
   > doInBackground():-This step is used to perform background computation that can take a long time. You cannot update any UI in this method.
   >
   > onPostExecute():-This is invoked after completion of background task and it will update the UI.

I have defined WebView in xml like following way,

```
  <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"/>
```

And in MainActivity.java, I had wrote JSOUP code for remove the unnecessary portion of webpage

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView webview;
String url="http://pixelay.com/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    new MyAsynTask().execute();
}

private class MyAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document> {
    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        Document document = null;
        try {
            document= Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            document.getElementsByClass("main-navigation").remove();
            document.getElementsByClass("custom-header-image").remove();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return document;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
        super.onPostExecute(document);
        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url,document.toString(),"text/html","utf-8","");
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

**Now, it's time to see the result,**

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks fo the answer. I tried it and it's working but seems when I remove header there is white space left and that makes gap, do you know how can I remove that white space?

Comment: @Yupi I think that if you do an inspect element and remove those classes on the web (First) then you should see where the white space is coming from. In this way, you should be able to remove any extra tag. However, if you did it, can you show how you did? Thanks,

Comment: Hi, i use this code and its working but when i click any item and webview load new url, that url shows with  heaer and footer,please help me

Answer (score 2):

```
public class YourwebView extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:var footer = document.getElementById(\"footer\"); footer.parentNode.removeChild(footer); var header = document.getElementById(\"header-full\"); header.parentNode.removeChild(header);");
    }

}
```

And also make sure you have enabled javscript

```
YourwebView myWebClient = new YourwebView();
webview.setWebViewClient(myWebClient);
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I tried this. But after that there was the error, that it could not find the method

Comment: It worked. But after the webView loaded completely, it shows the header again

Answer (score 1):

Use `onPageStarted` method instead of `onPageFinished`.

From the Android Docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String))

**EDIT:** Reading the comments on other answers, I see you want the header to show again. Simply implement both `onPageStarted` and `onPageEnded`, hiding the header in one and showing it again in the other.