# How to get javascript hide header in webview

Tags: android, webview

My webview when load javascript onPageFinish to hide header my website code bellow:

My code :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    final WebView webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    CustomWebClient customWebClient=new CustomWebClient();
    webView.setWebViewClient(customWebClient);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://ticketgo.vn/blog");
}

class CustomWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl("https:ticketgo.vn/blog");
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('header').style.display='none';");

    }
}
```

}

My result how to fit it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fAUo.png)

Comment: I've answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47845586/8389034