# Remove the Navigation Bar in Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

So I want to load only the body of the html and I want to remove the Navigation Bar. Is it possible to remove navigation bar of the website in WebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSOUP, like this:

```
 document= Jsoup.connect(url).get();
 document.getElementsByClass("main-navigation").remove();
```

checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844004/how-to-remove-the-header-in-android-webview-while-loading)